# array cant be populated

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
function draw(data)
{
var i = 0;
var checkduplicates = new Array();
drawOne(i);
//console.log(checkduplicates) Problem!!!;

function drawOne(i)
{
         //photos is a object that has been omitted for simplicity
    var picinfo = photos[Math.floor(Math.random()*photos.length)];
    checkduplicates.push(picinfo);

    img.onload = function()
    {
        var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
        // Draw pieces
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,132,150);
        //ctx.fillText("haha",0,0);
        ctx.drawImage(frame,0,0,133,152);
        i++;
        if (i != canvaslength)
        {
             drawOne(i);
        }
    }
    //console.log(checkduplicates.length);
}
}
```

Hey, I declared the drawOne function inside the draw function, so that the local variable checkduplicates is accessible to the inner function drawOne. However, after the drawOne function runs 16 times, the array checkduplicates is supposed to be populated with objects, which is proved by the console.log inside drawOne that shows 16 objects are in the array. However, the console.log function, which I marked with "Problem", shows that the array has only very first object meanwhile others console.logs show the array is full of objects. I dont understand why since the only way to modify the array is through the "push" method, which has been called for 16 times and if I comment out the img.onload part, the console.log with comment "problem" shows the array is full of objects. I intentionally omitted other codes for simplicity  and my firebug doesnt complain for bugs. Thank you

Comment: Wait - where does "i" come from? And "photos"?  And "checkduplicates"?  You have not posted enough code.

Comment: i is initialized to be 0; I will fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using asynchronous recursion, the initial call to `drawOne` will return after the first iteration. The iterations will continue when the first image has loaded, and when you have exited out of the `draw` function so that the browser regains control so that it can handle events.

So, that the array only contains a single item after the first iteration is not a problem at all, it's the expected result from the iteration method that you have used.

Comment: Ok, but I still dont understand that how come the inner console.log shows that the array is populated but the outside console.log shows the array only holds one object. But aren't they the same array? there is supposed to be only one memory address associated with "checkduplicates"? Thank you

Comment: @Clinteney Hui: It's the same array, but at different points in time. The logging in `drawOne` is executed once first, showing the length of one, then the logging in `Draw` is executed showing the same result. After that the first image loads and the first `onload` event is handled, and the logging in `drawOne` shows the length of two. Then follows the rest `onload` events with increasing size for the array. It's not possible for the array length to be anything other than one inside the `Draw` function, because the first `onload` event is not handled as long as you are inside the function.